# Can this MySQL Be Run in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am tasked with keeping a sequence number in a table sequential for a certain product ID.  Apart from the argument over whether this is a good thing (I lost the argument), can this SQL statement be run in JDBC?  Actually, I guess there are two statements here.  We are using Spring JDBCTemplates.

```
SET @rank:=0; 

UPDATE my_table
SET product_set=@rank:=@rank+1 
WHERE product_id = '123456';
```

Comment: Your query only makes sense if you update a *range* of rows, otherwise you would just code the single value you need. Also, you probably want update the result of an `order by product_id` - there's no guarantee that rows are ordered by id

Comment: @Bohemian I was working on the assumption that `product_id` wasn't unique in `my_table` and was instead a foreign key, so there'd be (potentially) several rows with the same `product_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a variable inside your query like this

```
UPDATE my_table
inner join (select @rank:= 0) r
SET product_set = @rank:=@rank+1 
WHERE product_id = '123456';
```

Comment: Which part of the question is this supposed to answer? I'm thoroughly confused about what exactly it is this is saying. Is the query in the question flat out wrong, is it only wrong when trying to run it using JDBC, or is this simply a better way of doing the same thing?

Comment: It is saying that if it won't run in JDBC then you can overcome that problem by doing it like the above example.

Comment: Except for the ORDER BY, this is exactly what I was looking for.